# Cant create object in cloudboost using android studio

Tags: android, mbaas, cloudboost

Getting text from a EditText Field.  And attempting to set it to a new CloudObject.  But Nothing happens when i click the Button.

```
 btnUpdteStts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

 String caption = edtxtPost.getText().toString().trim();

         final CloudObject obj = new CloudObject("Status");
            try {
                obj.set("Cap",caption);
            } catch (CloudException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                obj.save(new CloudObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(CloudObject x, CloudException t) throws CloudException {

                        if(x!=null) {
                            Intent goHome = new Intent(Post.this, HomeRoom.class);
                            startActivity(goHome);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (CloudException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

       Toast.makeText(Post.this,"Problem",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: "Nothing happens when i click the Button"  - If there is an exception, there is an error log. If x is null, nothing will happen. Those are the only reasons I see in this code for the behavior you describe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem not to have handled the case in the callback where `x==null` in which case exception `t!=null`. Print the exception message and you should be able to see the problem.